# Where does GitLab omnibus store ci log files?

Tags: gitlab

When viewing a raw CI log file, such as this one

```
https://acmeco.net/acmeco/acmeco/angular-ui/-/jobs/334040/raw
```

I can see content such as

```
net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) (manager.go:235:15s)
```

I want to find all ci jobs that produced the same error. Where are these logs stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the setting in your `gitlab.rb` file,

- If `artifacts_object_store_enabled` is enabled and you're using the [Object Storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html), the artifacts will store in whatever the value is of `artifacts_object_store_remote_directory` under a file called `job.log`. [For information on how to search through all jobs, see *"Does GitLab support searching across jobs for specific strings?
  "*.](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17255/18965)
- [There is also an NFS backend](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/nfs.html)
- [There is also local storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/terraform_state.html#using-local-storage)

For more information see

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html#storing-job-artifacts