# Does GitLab support searching logs across jobs for specific strings?

Tags: gitlab, logging

I need to find all jobs that failed in a specific fashion, a few methods are viable

- One method that would be viable is finding where GitLab stores its log files, and searching them with something like Grep. [I asked that question here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17254/18965).
- Another method would be using native GitLab search functionality to search the logs. Does such functionality exist?

Comment: The functionality seems not implemented but it was raised here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363640 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality doesn't yet exist in the UI, though internally job logs are upload as a job artifact. And you can search them with a little bit of work. The backing store is configured in your, `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`.

- If `artifacts_object_store_enabled` is enabled and you're using the [Object Storage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html), the artifacts will store in whatever the value is of `artifacts_object_store_remote_directory` under a file called `job.log`. Assuming that value is `artifacts`, and you're using something like [minio](https://min.io/), you can search across jobs for a specific failure with

  - `mc find` and `mc cat`,

    ```sh
    # In the example below, I'm looking for failures that contain Client.Timeout
    mc find minio/artifacts \
      --name 'job.log'      \
      --exec 'sh -c "mc cat {} | grep Client\.Timeout | xargs -r echo {time} {}; exit 0"' \
      | tee /tmp/client_timeout.log
    ```

    In my experience, this is just too slow as `mc find` isn't indexed it's just looking for any bucket with the name `job.log`.
  - A faster method is to lean on the database. Gitlab ships a PostgreSQL client wrapper called `gitlab-psql` which allows you to connect to underlying PostgreSQL datastore. After you connect with `gitlab-psql` can query for all `file.log` and [get the relative path to the bucket from the result](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17298/18965). You can easily tool this by creating a batch file of commands for [s5cmd](https://github.com/peak/s5cmd) log,

    ```
    \t
    \a
    \o /tmp/pull_logs.s5cmd
    SELECT FORMAT(
      'cp s3://artifacts/%s /tmp/job_%s.log',
      to_bucket_path(ci_job_artifacts),
      id
    )
    FROM ci_job_artifacts
    WHERE file = 'job.log'
    AND expire_at IS NULL
    AND file_store = 2;
    ```

    Which will generate a file you can run with something like [s5cmd](https://github.com/peak/s5cmd) to pull down all of your logs from the Gitlab Object store. You'd run it by setting up your `~/.aws/credentials` and running (example with minio).

    ```
    s5cmd --endpoint-url https://minio.acme.net run /tmp/pull_logs.s5cmd
    ```
- You can also use [NFS](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/nfs.html). If you're using NFS for artifact storage, it's as easy as going to the mount point and searching with ripgrep.